# How do I add two ArrayLists of different classes that extend an abstract class into one ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have the two following arraylists:

```
private List<Manager> _managers = new ArrayList<Manager>(); //Manager extends User
private List<Employee> _employees = new ArrayList<Employee>(); //Employee extends User
```

I want to have an arraylist that combines both of these, storing all users, both employees and managers.

Currently I am trying the following solution:

```
private List<User> _usrs = new ArrayList<User>();
/*
 *  function that I use before I get the current user list, preventing getting a outdated version of it
 */
public void refreshUserList() {
    this._usrs.clear();   //prevent duplicates 
    this._usrs.addAll(_employees); //add all employees to user list
    this._usrs.addAll(_managers);  //add all managers to user list
}
```

Is this a good way to solve this problem? 
I'm having some nullPointer iterator issues when iterating this list and before I get into solving this issue, I'd like to know if the problem isn't right here. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to keep the order?

Comment: No, the order is irrelevant.

Comment: I just found the cause to my issue, it was indeed an iterator issue and I just solved it! Thanks for the quick support to everyone that already suggested different answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `Employee` and the `Manager` classes both extend the `User` class, then yes, this is a good solution. If you want to prevent duplicates, however, you can use a Set:

```
private Set<User> _usrs = new HashSet<>();
/*
 *  function that I use before I get the current user set, preventing getting a outdated version of it
 */
public void refreshUserList() {
    this._usrs.addAll(_employees); //add all employees to user set
    this._usrs.addAll(_managers);  //add all managers to user set
}
```

You don't need to call `clear();`, since Sets do not add duplicate elements.

This way, you will lose the special variables/methods that appear only for  Managers or Employees, since all you will have will be the variables/methods available for Users. However, if you cast each `User` instance of your `_usrs` Set to `Manager` or `Employee`, then you can still get those special elements/methods:

```
for (User user : _usrs) {
    if (user instanceof Manager) {
        Manager mng = (Manager) user;
        mng.manage(); // or whatever managers do that employees don't
    } else { //if no other classes extend the User class
        Employee emp = (Employee) user;
        emp.work(); // or whatever employees do that managers don't :P
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will consider using a set instead of a list as you suggest, duplicates are something I really want to avoid.

Comment: I just found my problem, I had an issue iterating my list, I was stepping out of bounds and getting a null class... Thank you very much though, your answer was quite well done and useful!

Comment: @Maslor I 'm glad that it helped. Use the ehanced `for` loop, like the one in my second block of code, to avoid such exceptions in the future. Plus, they are easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Set instead of a List which would solve your duplicate problem, as for the iterator issue you'd have to add more information about where it's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!, I found the issue (it was indeed in an iterator issue, which I just solved).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your `Manager` and `Employee` classes are extending/ implementing your `User` class, Only then you will be able to combine the two arraylists.

If you want to prevent duplicates, use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), if you also want to maintain the order, use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

```
private LinkedHashSet<User> _usrs = new LinkedHashSet<User>();
public void refreshUserList() {
    usrs.clear();   //prevent duplicates 
    usrs.addAll(_employees); //add all employees to user list
    usrs.addAll(_managers);  //add all managers to user list
}
```